# How to change the first day of week on wingpanel calendar?

Tags: wingpanel

I'd like to change the first day of week on the little calendar that shows up at the wingpanel. At the current state it shows Sunday as the first day of the week, but I'd like it to be Monday. How can I change this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a locale from a culture where that is the norm.

You can try to make that a sticky setting for your user in the system, by putting something like that in `~/.xsessionrc`

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.utf-8
export LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
export LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Which is basically "I want system messages in American, but time and measurement in UK English". Monday is the first day of the week in UK culture.

Log out and back in for that to work.

Or, you could try make that a system-wide change.
Assuming your `locale` outputs `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, find and change `first_weekday 1` to `first_weekday 2` in the US locale file (do a `sudo nano /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US`). Then do a `sudo locale-gen` and reboot.

The latter is not recommended in a server setting, but you should be fine on your own machine.

Comment: Thanks for this. My locale has an incorrect `first_weekday`, where do I report it?

Comment: What's called "upstream" -- but I'd first get on IRC and put it out there for people to verify, so you don't mis-report stuff and don't waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think that depends on your timezone, I'm using the Asuncion Paraguay timezone and I have monday as first day of the week.